# VBA copy pivot table in the same sheet and use it

Tags: excel, copy-paste, pivot-table, vba

Hi I am copying a pivot table I have on the same sheet and I would like to use the copied pivot table by changing some items. The problem is when I copy pivot table, how do i identify the new pivot table name to use it?

My main goal is to create multiple pivot tables on the same worksheet. Pivot wizard does not let me do that.

My Code:

```
        ws.Select
        TotalColumns = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Counting total columns
        TotalRows = ws.Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count 'Counting total rows
        Set PRange = ws.UsedRange 'found a new function to use do not need to use above fields, but keeping them just incase
        wsPivotStats.Select
        Set CreateStatsAppPt = wsPivotStats.PivotTableWizard(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange, TableDestination:=wsPivotStats.Range("B4"), TableName:="StatsPt1")
        Set StatsAppViewPt = wsPivotStats.PivotTables("StatsPt1")
```

Adding rows and columns to above table and...

```
   ActiveSheet.PivotTables("StatsPt1").PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True
   Selection.Copy
   wsPivotStats.Range("B22").Select
   wsPivotStats.Paste
   Set StatsRevViewPt = wsPivotStats.PivotTables("PivotTable2")
           StatsRevViewPt.Select
    With StatsRevViewPt.PivotFields(CaseClas)
               .Orientation = xlColumnField
               .Position = 1
              ' .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, _
                False, False)
    End With
```

Comment: Got it working...but can't answer the questions less than 8 hours :(

Answer (score 0):

after a line wsPivotStats.Paste use

```
set StatsRevViewPt= wsPivotStats.PivotTables(wsPivotStats.PivotTables.count)
```